# Why the files which are not present on desktop are being listed on terminal?

Tags: 12.04

I'm currently using Ubuntu 12.04. I have only one folder on my Desktop. I used "ls -l " command to list all the items on my Desktop. Even if I had only one folder, it listed so many other things. Is that a possible bug?

Comment: you should show which files you cannot see on desktop but can see in terminal

Comment: 1. No. 2. Please include the actual command and results.

Comment: i am a new user and i lack reputation to post an image. i had only folder called "Folder" on desktop. I used "cd Desktop" and then "ls -l" . I should have got only "Folder" as the result. But i got some files which were permanently deleted earlier.

Comment: provide a link to an external page with your screenshot

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll find your answer [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/147859/why-are-some-files-and-folders-hidden) and some more [here](http://www.wikiwand.com/en/Hidden_file_and_hidden_directory).

It's not a bug, some files are hidden because they are needed by some programs (for configurations, backup files, etc) but which are generally not needed by the user directly, and are made hidden to clear up the visual space.

For example when you edit a file say with `gedit`, when you create or modify a text file, it will create a new file with a '~' at the end which is used as a backup file, which autosaves your work automatically and can be restored if `gedit` or your computer crashes and you forgot to save your work. But you don't to see it to be able to use it, so it's made hidden.

Comment: The "Desktop" folder does NOT hold hidden files by default. Only /home/$USER/ does. Besides that he explicitly stated "ls -l" and would require to use "ls -la" for hidden files to be shown. No, to me the questions is unclear to me.

Comment: Good point. And yes what I said is more for the `-a` option more than anything.  But it does show the backup files like I explained so I'm guessing I'm not entirely wrong either.  And you can put hidden folders and files on the desktop, even if by default apps will tend to put them where you said.

Comment: sure but I would assume TS would know if he did that ;-)

Comment: Good point again^^ I'll leave this as it is though for now, until new elements arrive.